# Sharp drop in active installs on Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I've noticed a one day 10% drop in active installs of my app. Any reason for that? Did anything change on Google's side? Some points to consider:

- The installs and uninstalls **graphs do not correlate**, and
- There was no new version released in a while, nor API changes that broke functionality

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not a programming question.

Comment: Play store stats are super flaky lately, wait a few days and the drop might get magically erased.

Comment: Thank you. Have you stumbled across a source online I can show my team?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be from a new ranking algorithm google has put in, lots of sites are recently reporting this(you can read about it in the links):

https://variety.com/2018/gaming/news/developers-sudden-drop-downloads-on-google-play-store-1202861850/

https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/android-developers-see-sudden-drop-in-install-rates-google-play-algorithms-1876405

https://www.androidheadlines.com/2018/07/some-android-devs-panicking-over-sudden-app-install-rate-drops.html

Comment: These links are from 3 weeks ago and they talk about a drop in daily install, not in active installs. In my case, I see a sudden drop of my latest version (3.0.2) the 17th of July and other versions seem to have a quite nice rise: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhbvw2bs30f4r4u/error-googleplay-stackoverflow.PNG?raw=1